# Button and EditTextbox and layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout

**This is my code. So when button is clicked, I have two edit text boxes that show up everytime, Button is clicked. They are coming up and down, instead I want them to be side by side. 
Also I wanted to know that can I change the linear layout to absolute, since I want the button position to be at the middle of the page. Also, I want when I click the button edit text boxes should go to the top not at the bottom.
Hope so, I made this questions clear.**

**java code :**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class PlusbuttonActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        LinearLayout root;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText t = new EditText(PlusbuttonActivity.this);
                EditText a = new EditText(PlusbuttonActivity.this);

                t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                a.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                addViewToRoot(t);
                addViewToRoot(a);
            } 
        });

        }

        private void addViewToRoot(View v){
          root.addView(v);
        }

    }
```

**xml file:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="+" android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make them side by side change linearlayout orientation="horizontal" but to me it sounds like you'd rather play around with RelativeLayout. Look it up before you get stuck and try to play with it http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html.

Comment: i know how to do that.. as you can c I am doing it with java code.. :( how do i implement that in java :(